# Does yosys preserve port ordering?

Tags: yosys

Does yosys preserve the ordering of input/output ports for modules/cells?  Is the ordering in the RTL guaranteed to match the ordering of the verilog  when it is read/written?  Will the ordering ever be changed "unexpectedly" by yosys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yosys does store the order in which module ports are declared in `RTLIL::Wire::port_id`. Positional parameters on instances are renamed to `$1, $2, $3, ...`. The `hierarchy` command then uses the `port_id` property to correctly rename the ports on cell instances during design elaboration.

When writing a module as verilog file the wire `port_id` property is used to determine the order in which ports are declared in the module header.

So yes: Yosys does preserve ordering of input/output ports for modules and resolves the names of positional parameters in cell instances.

When `hierarchy` is not run or the declaration of a cell type is not available, then the positional parameters in those cell instances are not resolved and they are again dumped as positional parameters when the design is written as verilog file.

**Edit:** In response to the comment: The following example plugin (portsigdemo.cc) demonstrates how to create a SigSpec containing all module ports / cell ports in the order of the port declarations in the corresponding module:

```
#include "kernel/yosys.h"
#include "kernel/consteval.h"

USING_YOSYS_NAMESPACE
PRIVATE_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

SigSpec get_portsig(Module *module, string direction, Cell *cell = nullptr)
{
    if (cell)
        log_assert(cell->type == module->name);

    SigSpec sig;
    dict<int, SigSpec> sigs;

    for (auto wire : module->wires())
    {
        bool selected = false;

        if (direction == "in")
            selected = wire->port_input;
        else if (direction == "out")
            selected = wire->port_output;
        else
            log_abort();

        if (selected) {
            if (cell) {
                if (cell->hasPort(wire->name))
                    sigs[wire->port_id] = cell->getPort(wire->name);
                else if (cell->hasPort(stringf("$%d", wire->port_id)))
                    sigs[wire->port_id] = cell->getPort(stringf("$%d", wire->port_id));
                else
                    log_abort();
            } else {
                sigs[wire->port_id] = wire;
            }
        }
    }

    sigs.sort();
    for (auto &it : sigs)
        sig.append(it.second);

    return sig;
}

struct PortsigDemoPass : public Pass
{
    PortsigDemoPass():Pass("portsigdemo") { }

    virtual void execute(vector < string >, Design * design)
    {
        for (auto module : design->modules())
        {
            log("Module %s:\n", log_id(module));
            log("  Inputs: %s\n", log_signal(get_portsig(module, "in")));
            log("  Outputs: %s\n", log_signal(get_portsig(module, "out")));

            for (auto cell : module->cells())
            {
                auto cell_type_mod = cell->module->design->module(cell->type);
                if (cell_type_mod) {
                    log("  Cell %s (%s):\n", log_id(cell), log_id(cell->type));
                    log("    Inputs: %s\n", log_signal(get_portsig(cell_type_mod, "in", cell)));
                    log("    Outputs: %s\n", log_signal(get_portsig(cell_type_mod, "out", cell)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
} PortsigDemoPass;

PRIVATE_NAMESPACE_END
```

Example usage:

```
$ cat > portsigdemo.v << EOT
module mod1 (input [3:0] A, B, output [3:0] Y);
  mod2 mod2_inst0 (.P(A[0]), .Q(B[0]), .X(Y[0]));
  mod2 mod2_inst1 (.P(B[1]), .Q(A[1]), .X(Y[1]));
  mod2 mod2_inst2 (A[2], B[2], Y[2]);
  mod2 mod2_inst3 (B[3], A[3], Y[3]);
endmodule

module mod2 (input P, Q, output X);
  assign X = P ^ Q;
endmodule
EOT

$ yosys-config --build portsigdemo.so portsigdemo.cc
$ yosys -m portsigdemo.so -p portsigdemo portsigdemo.v
...
-- Running command `portsigdemo' --
Module mod2:
  Inputs: { \Q \P }
  Outputs: \X
Module mod1:
  Inputs: { \B \A }
  Outputs: \Y
  Cell mod2_inst3 (mod2):
    Inputs: { \A [3] \B [3] }
    Outputs: \Y [3]
  Cell mod2_inst2 (mod2):
    Inputs: { \B [2] \A [2] }
    Outputs: \Y [2]
  Cell mod2_inst1 (mod2):
    Inputs: { \A [1] \B [1] }
    Outputs: \Y [1]
  Cell mod2_inst0 (mod2):
    Inputs: { \B [0] \A [0] }
    Outputs: \Y [0]
```

PS: In `portsigdemo.v`, the cells (module instances) mod1.mod2_inst0 and mod1.mod2_inst1 are using named parameters (the name of the module port is given) and the cells mod1.mod2_inst2 and mod1.mod2_inst3 are using positional parameters (the module port is determined by the order of parameters).

Comment: What does "Positional parameters on instances" mean?  I don't understand most of this answer beyond the existence of port_id.    What I'm really trying to do is get a SigSpec for all cell inputs and a SigSpec for all cell outputs, where they are ordered according to the Verilog definition.

Comment: @ClifforVienna Thank you very much, I understand now, but it still seems like this does not apply for builtin cell types.  Where are the ports defined for builtin cells, and do they have an associated ordering?

Comment: @JeremySalwen You are correct: The builtin cell types have no associated port ordering, as the ports of builtin cell types are always referred to by name.